# Resetting conda default channel after deletion in Conda environement - Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-forge

If I delete the **default** conda channel and would like to add it back again later, how do I do that? is there a URL link just like for [**conda-forge** channel URL link](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/introduction.html#display-conda-forge-packages-in-anaconda-navigator) that I just add (because I can't find one)? or writing "default" is just gonna work?

- I added `conda-forge` channel URL to my environment using Anaconda Navigator.
- I want to delete the `default` channel to test some things out.
- I want to be able to add the `default` channel back later.

[anaconda-navigator-env-channels-preview-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOQ3d.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conda recognizes `defaults` as a special name. Any other non-URLs are interpreted as channels on [Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/). E.g.,

- "conda-forge": https://anaconda.org/conda-forge
- "anaconda": https://anaconda.org/anaconda
- "bioconda": https://anaconda.org/bioconda

Unless you're using a local mirror or proxy, most users never need to use a URL.